# How to fix 'HTTP-404' error, during GET request in REST web service using spring boot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

My sample spring boot REST web service gives 404 error, and I am not sure what went wrong

```
package com.in28minutes.springboot.studentservices;
@SpringBootApplication
public class StudentServicesApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(StudentServicesApplication.class, args);
}

}

package com.in28minutes.springboot.controller;
@RestController
public class StudentController {

@Autowired
private StudentService studentService;

@GetMapping("/students/{studentId}/courses")
public List<Course> retrieveCoursesForStudent(@PathVariable String 
    studentId) {
    return studentService.retrieveCourses(studentId);
}

@GetMapping("/students/{studentId}/courses/{courseId}")
public Course retrieveDetailsForCourse(@PathVariable String studentId,
        @PathVariable String courseId) {
    return studentService.retrieveCourse(studentId, courseId);
}

}
```

My Request  from POSTMan REST request sender: 
    http://localhost:8080/students/stu1/courses/course1

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
 <groupId>com.in28minutes.springboot</groupId>
 <artifactId>student-services</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>student-services</name>
 <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

 <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

Response:

{
    "timestamp": "2018-12-28T02:48:00.185+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/students/stu1/courses/course1"
}

Comment: i tried running your code and i am not getting 404. are you sure that this application is hosted on 8080 ?

Comment: can you post the stack trace and your pom.xml?

Comment: updated the post with pom.xml and http response.

Comment: @SoumaliChatterjee are you able to invoke http://localhost:8080/students/stu1/courses/course1 directly from chrome ?

Comment: Is your `server.port=8080` in application properties?

Comment: Kindly check Student Service Implementation file.

Comment: can you update the package structure @SoumaliChatterjee

Comment: @mkjh response to chrome request:                                                   
 Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Dec 28 09:54:51 IST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: @Deadpool updated package structure

Comment: these two classes are in same package `com.in28minutes.springboot.controller;`? @SoumaliChatterjee

Comment: its interesting that RequestMapping works, but GetMapping doesnt

Comment: @Deadpool, sorry updated package

Comment: updated try my answer @SoumaliChatterjee

Comment: also, check if there's any server.servlet.context-path property in application.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved, @Component needed to be added to Service class, along with @ComponentScan in the main application class:

```
package com.in28minutes.springboot.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.in28minutes.springboot.model.Course;
import com.in28minutes.springboot.model.Student;

@Component
public class StudentService {

public List<Course> retrieveCourses(String studentId) {
    Map<String, Course> courses = Student.getStudentObj(studentId).getCourses();
    List<Course> courseList = 
    courses.values().parallelStream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    return courseList;
 }

 public Course retrieveCourse(String studentId, String courseId) {
    return Student.getStudentObj(studentId).getCourses().get(courseId);
 }
```

}

```
package com.in28minutes.springboot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication 
@ComponentScan("com.in28minutes.springboot")
public class StudentServicesApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(StudentServicesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

As assumed, you have Controller classes in different package `com.in28minutes.springboot.controller;` and Spring boot main class in different package `com.in28minutes.springboot.studentservices;`

**@SpringBootApplication**

> By default `@SpringBootApplication` will only scan from the package of the class that declares this annotation.
>
> This is a convenience annotation that is equivalent to declaring @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan.
>
> If specific packages are not defined, scanning will occur from the package of the class that declares this annotation.

use `@ComponentScan` to scan controller package

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.in28minutes.springboot.controller"})
 @SpringBootApplication
 public class StudentServicesApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 SpringApplication.run(StudentServicesApplication.class, args);
     }
  }
```

**More Info :** [ref](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-component-scan)

Comment: I was going to suggest the OP add the "mappings" lines from his startup log into his post.  But you got there first with your reply about the "packages" mismatch.  You're absolutely correct!  I'm crossing my fingers that it resolves the problem :)

Comment: Thank you, it should resolve the problem, because it is clear his package are not organized @paulsm4

Comment: thanks for both of your amazing follow-up. Resolved the issue, as below.

Comment: Thank you!  This helped me greatly.